# Why is $wpdb->get_results failing on certain tables but not others (which have data)?

Tags: database

I'm trying to pull some custom data from a [Cart66](http://www.cart66.com) table.

My code works whenever I pull results from standard WP table in (my array is populated and the print_r shows that data), but not with any Cart66 tables (it prints an empty array).

I am absolutely certain that I've got data in these tables (I've rechecked that I'm using the correct table names about 1,000,000 times). I've tried two Cart66 tables which have data in them.

The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) says the get_results class should work with any table, not just standard tables. I thought it might be the underscore that was causing trouble, but underscores are supposed to be fine, and indeed, standard WP tables with underscores work fine.

```
$rawproducts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->cart66_products" );
print_r($rawproducts);
```

This is maddening! Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the ouput for the `print_r` of `$rawproducts`? Also, just concatenate strings for clarity: `'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->cart66_products`.

Comment: $wpdb->cart66_products is probably not a property of $wpdb. I'm not familiar with Cart66, but it looks like they probably know what they're doing so I'm assuming they prepended the current WordPress prefix to the table name. If that's the case, you should always use that when referencing the table as in {$wpdb->prefix}my_table_name - note you don't need an underscore, because that's part of the prefix.

Comment: Does Cart66 not include any extensions to WP_Query that you can use, rather than having to manually create the SQL? It's a pretty big plugin - I would imagine they have some API for developers like you. See if you can stay out of the SQL as much as possible.

Comment: Geert: As I mentioned, the output is an empty array - "Array()".

Comment: Tom: this helps me get to an answer. I misunderstood the codex. When I used just the table name, it worked fine (without $wpdb->). I'm still working out the syntax of {$wpdb->prefix}table_name. See below on fischi's answer.

Comment: Tom: Cart66 actually included surprisingly few built-in functions like this. I really wish they did. At least, after much searching, they seemed to have almost nothing built-in.

Comment: @jfacemyer You have to use an `@` in front of a name to ping people. You also have to remove spaces if it´s a name that has more than one word. When typing the `@`, you´ll see that autocomplete pop up. Just click on it.

Comment: @jfacemyer are you sure that the cart66 tables have the prefix included? if it works with just the tablename, i suppose cart66 does not use the prefix..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do not have to specify the $wpdb again in your query, but be sure that your table uses the prefix, if it has one. if it doesn't, skip the part with the prefix.
also, you should always prepare a manually added query first.
this should do it:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s", "{$wpdb->prefix}cart66_products" );
$rawproducts = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
print_r($rawproducts);
```

Comment: `prepare()` is pretty much the same as `sprintf`. You have to use `%s` for string and `%d` for digit replacements. Else it helps nothing. It would be the same as `sprintf( "hello $bad_code" );`.

Comment: This didn't work out of the box for me. I got it to work by putting in the whole table name only and not using $wpdb->table, but I'd like this to work so I can have a portable plugin that's set up correctly.

Comment: @fischi

OK, so this works fine:

`    $thisquery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}cart66_products" );
    $rawproducts = $wpdb->get_results( $thisquery );
    print_r($rawproducts);`

but not this:

`    $thisquery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s", "{$wpdb->prefix}cart66_products" );
    $rawproducts = $wpdb->get_results( $thisquery );
    print_r($rawproducts);`

Comment: @jfacemyer You have to strip white spaces from before and after code to get code highlighting in comments. Also: "didn´t work" is a no-go. You´ll have to provide full error statements. Else it´s guessing.

Comment: @kaiser thank you, of course you are right here. i was under the impression `prepare()` also checks for bad characters. so, in conclusion, if you do not enter user input in your query, the `prepare()` is not really necessary?

Comment: @fischi You always need to `prepare` (even without user input - someone could insert into your query by code), if the core function doesn´t do it by herself (no guidelines here - search core). The important thing is that you `prepare` everything that´s not a SQL statement, like tablenames, col names, etc.

Comment: @kaiser - all I get is an empty array. (I apologize for my stupidity - how would I get any error codes produced?)

Comment: @kaiser - thanks for the markup tutorial - I couldn't figure that out for the life of me :/

Comment: You can't use sprintf replacement for table names - `$wpdb->prepare( "%s", 'foo' )` will put single quotes around 'foo', which is not valid MySQL syntax for referring to tables.

Answer (score 4):

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        SELECT * FROM %s
    ",
    "{$wpdb->prefix}cart66_products" 
);
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

$wpdb->show_errors();
echo '<pre>';
    // Show results
    echo "<hr />Results:\n";
    print_r( $results );

    // Show errors
    echo "<hr />Errors:\n";
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) AND defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) AND WP_DEBUG AND defined( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY' ) AND WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY )
    {
        $wpdb->print_error();
    }
echo '</pre>';

// Savely remove errors for guest or non admins
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

More info [about error handling inside WPDB can be found here in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors).

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cart66_products';
$i = 0;
$obj = [];

$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $table_name"
);

$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    $query
);
$wpdb->show_errors();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $obj[$i] = $row;
    $i++;  
}
    echo '<pre>';
    echo "<hr />Results:\n";
    echo json_encode($obj);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]! Please explain how this solves the problem.